# Angular JS :Hide/Close a Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing issues while closing the Modal in Angular JS

**HTML**

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="gridSet">
            <div class="gridStyle adjustViewPort" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

            // Here is the HTML template for MODAL.

            <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <p>No Events Found</p>
                <p><button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="myClickEvent()">OK</button></p>
                </div>
            </script>
        </div>

  </div>
```

And in **controller.js** looks like

```
$scope.modalInstance=$modal.open({templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'});

//This should run. But, every time only Cancelled is logged.
$scope.modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                    console.log('Success'); // This is never executed.
                    }, function() {
                    console.log('Cancelled');
                    })['finally'](function(){
                    $scope.modalInstance = undefined  
                    });
```

I have tried to hide the modal by `this.$hide();` in `myClickEvent` But, the function is not called at all.

Code from [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tzAiMMvYdNqI6qIoMnE?p=preview) from which I have copied the code.

Looking for 1) Hide the modal after few seconds using `$timeout`
            2) Close the modal when user selects OK.

**UPDATE**

Issue is the Code in Plunker Shows `$modalInstance` as dependency which I am not able to inject.

Function 'ng-click="myClickEvent()"' calls a function in controller which is as below.

```
$scope.myClickEvent=function(){
     alert('the function is called.');
}
```

But, the there is no alert.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Hi, what is the actual issue ? Looking at the Plunker example you copied your code from - there is all what you need, I was about to write you a sample code - but I will end up with the similar code as is in the example !  $hide - what is that ? You should be using `$modalInstance.close($scope.something);`  Have a look here maybe it will help : http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/ALsdF

Comment: You need to post actual relevant code.. for us to undertand. what is `this.$hide()` anyways and what is `this` ?

Comment: ng-click="myClickEvent()" -- this function shoud be defined in your modal controller.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused. I have updated the question. The Plunker example has `$modalInstance` as dependency which I am not able to use in my controller.

Comment: Just a doubt!! if u not gettin alert in ng-click, u might forget to add controller in tag - <div class="container" ng-controller="ModalCtrl">

Answer (score 0):

Use `close()` method:

```
 $scope.close = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well. But the issue is $scope.close is not getting called.I have `alert('Hi')` in `myCLickEvent` but that dosen't show up.